# PHP/CSS -Format content that include multiple selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="main">
  <aside class="readableCenterAside left"> ## Content 1 ## </aside>
  <aside class="readableCenterAside right"> ## Content 2 ## </aside>
</div>
```

and this in my CSS:

```
.readableCenterAside {
  width: 12.5%;
}
.right { float: right; }
.left { float: left; }
```

Is it possible to format content that are of multiple selectors? For instance, I'd like to add `padding-left:1em;` to Content 1 above and `padding-right: 1em;` to content 2 without creating a new selector like `.asideLeftPadding`.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
.readableCenterAside 'AND' .left { padding-left: 1em; }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect them **directly** with no `space` or `AND`

```
.readableCenterAside.left { padding-left: 1em; }
```

This is read as elements that have classes `readableCenterAside` **and** `left`

```css
.readableCenterAside {

  width: 12.5%;

}

.right {

  float: right;

}

.left {

  float: left;

}

.readableCenterAside.left {

  padding-left: 1em;

  color: green;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <aside class="readableCenterAside left">## Content 1 ##</aside>
  <aside class="readableCenterAside right">## Content 2 ##</aside>
</div>
```